# Converting json's array field to list

Tags: c#, json

```
        public List<Movie> getPopularMovies()
    {
        List<Movie> movies = null;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var task = client.GetAsync(url)
            .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
            {
                var response = taskwithresponse.Result;
                var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                jsonString.Wait();
                movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(jsonString.Result);
            });
        task.Wait();
        return movies;
    }
```

Json to convert

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/xfWac8MTYDxujaxgPVcRD9yZaul.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "After his career is destroyed, a brilliant but arrogant surgeon gets a new lease on life when a sorcerer takes him under his wing and trains him to defend the world against evil.",
      "release_date": "2016-10-25",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        12,
        14,
        878
      ],
      "id": 284052,
      "original_title": "Doctor Strange",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "Doctor Strange",
      "backdrop_path": "/hETu6AxKsWAS42tw8eXgLUgn4Lo.jpg",
      "popularity": 55.113822,
      "vote_count": 598,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.99
    }
  ],
  "total_results": 19676,
  "total_pages": 984
}
```

I'd like to set `movies` as `results` array. My solution (what I found here) is about setting `movies` as the whole json (pagem results, total_results, total_pages). In fact the json answer is a single object.

How to get deeply inside this json (while converting) to set the `List<Movie> movies` to `results` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class for the entire response, with a list of movies on it.

```
response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(jsonString.Result);
movies = response.Movies;
```

Example classes:

```
public class JsonResponse {

   [JsonProperty("results")]
   public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("page")]
   public int Page { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("total_results")]
   public int TotalResults { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("total_pages")]
   public int TotalPages { get; set; }

}

public class Movie
{
    [JsonProperty("poster_path")]
    public string PosterPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("adult")]
    public bool Adule { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("overview")]
    public string Overview { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release_date")]
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("genre_ids")]
    public List<int> GenreIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("original_title")]
    public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("original_language")]
    public string OriginalLanguage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("backdrop_path")]
    public string BackdropPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("popularity")]
    public double Popularity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vote_count")]
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("video")]
    public bool Video { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vote_average")]
    public double VoteAverage { get; set; }
}
```